# Is Lift-tig welding the same as lift-arc welding?

Tags: welding

I am a completely new not-even-started starter in welding.

I would like to know is Lift-tig welding the same as Lift-arc welding?
If not, what are the differences?

Comment: Arc welding uses rods so they are consumable.

Comment: hi @SolarMike how about Lift-tig, does it use rod as well?

Comment: Do you know what TIG welding is? or how it works? What about MIG?

Comment: @SolarMike I read about it already, even watched Youtube videos. But when they were doing demos for TIG welding, I did not see using filling metal, so I'm confused whether it requires filling metal when welding metals or not.

Comment: Doesn't a wire come out of the gun/welding pistol? ever seen the roll of wire changed?

Comment: @SolarMike it depends. If it's MIG or flux-cored, then yes. there will be a wire come out of the gun. But if it's TIG welding, nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TIG](https://weldingmastermind.com/the-lift-tig-welder-explained/) part of the name means tungsten inert gas.

When welding with either a MIG (metal inert gas) or TIG welder the welding surfaces are flooded with an inert gas, such as argon to prevent atmospheric gases, particularly oxygen, from reacting with the molten metal surfaces of the items being welded.

> A lift TIG welder is a machine that utilizes the TIG welding process with a lift start to the arc. This process involves a non-consumable tungsten electrode that runs a current through the metals to be joined, and is started by a light, smooth move of the torch that touches the tungsten to the metal—called a lift start. There are many benefits to TIG welding and a lift start as well.

[Arc welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding) is a form of welding that uses electricity to weld items, as opposed to [oxyacetylene welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxy-fuel_welding_and_cutting) which uses burning hot gas to weld items. It doesn't require the welding surfaces to be flooded with an inert gas.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for your answer, but I don't see it answers my question.

Comment: @Franva difficult to know what your question really is as we are not sure what you know or don't...

Comment: @SolarMike I shortened my question to make it focus on the thing I want to know. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: So "lift" is some sales bull ? Mig and tig always used some voltage adjustments to initiate the arc,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lift arc is a technique used for TIG Welding. Other technique used are: [Scratch-Start, lift arc and HF Ignition technique](https://www.materialwelding.com/what-is-the-scratch-start-lift-arc-and-hf-ignition-technique-in-tig-welding/).
When we say arc welding, it a broader term to describe welding processes relies in welding arc to produce heat. example are: Stick welding, MIG, TIG welding.